# Can't remove class

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to dubug next JavaScript code in on my HTML page:

```
var langs = document.getElementsByClassName('ss-code-language');
for (var i in langs)
{
    langs[i].classList.remove('ss-highlighted');
    document.getElementById('assa').classList.remove('ss-highlighted');
}
```

It works right. But when I remove next line:

```
var langs = document.getElementsByClassName('ss-code-language');
for (var i in langs)
{
    langs[i].classList.remove('ss-highlighted');
}
```

I get the

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined.

But I see in Watch that the item is defined. How the next line of code effect the previous.

Comment: Can you please print out the values for lang[i] in the loop in both situations?

Comment: they are the same in both cases. There are 2 elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName('ss-code-language')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object and not an array.

> elements is a [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements.

In  `for (var i in langs)` you're actually looping through all the object's properties.

**Looping through an HTMLCollection:**

```
 collection = document.getElementsByClassName('ss-code-language');
 var len = collection.length //see below - accessing length is expensive!
 for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
      collection.item(i) /* ... */
 }
```

**Fix**:
Caching the `length` property is recommended when using HTMLCollection. see more at:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a
- http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html

(thanks to @Benjamin Gruenbaum)

Comment: +1 This is the more correct answer, the only thing I'd change is _maybe_ caching the length (since it's not an array) but that's really not very important and not a big deal. Also, generally it's best not to iterate arrays or array like objects with `for... in`

Comment: You're right! --added `Fix` --And thank you for the content edits.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how the second line affects the first, but you will for sure solve it by adding a check:

```
var langs = document.getElementsByClassName('ss-code-language');
for (var i in langs) {
    if (typeof langs[i].classList != 'undefined') {
        langs[i].classList.remove('ss-highlighted');
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work... but is not fun :(... the original question was fun to think about.

Comment: Lol, I would love to step through that, @HighAley - can you please print out the values for lang[i] in the loop in both situations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use console.log();  for debug:

Example:

```
var hello = "hello world!";
console.log(hello);
```

This print you "hello world" on web browser console.

For your problem you should use the "typeof" here a source that help you 
[How to use "typeof"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Here a solution:

```
var langs = document.getElementsByClassName('ss-code-language');
for (var i in langs){
   if ( typeof langs[i] === 'undefined' || 
        typeof langs[i].classList === 'undefined')
        continue;
   langs[i].classList.remove('ss-highlighted');       
}
```

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a bug of the Chrome debugger.
I tested this script in the IE and there is alright.
And this script works right in Chrome without debugging.